# Initialize a controller with my root controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I'm using an open source class for sliding the view. The slide function works perfectly when the app launches, but when I change the view or call the segue method, and then come back to `HomeViewController`, the slide function stops working.  It only works when the `HomeVC` is launched for the first time. Please help me here.

In `AppDelegate.m` file :

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method is as below:

```
UIStoryboard *storybrd = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
HomeViewController *controller = [storybrd instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];

// setup slide navigation view controller instance
MWFSlideNavigationViewController * slideNavCtl = [[MWFSlideNavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];    
// slideNavCtl.panEnabled = YES;

self.window.rootViewController = slideNavCtl;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is as below:

> -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
>
> ```
> if(tableView == self.tableView1)
> {
>
>
>
>
> [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"CommVC"
>                           sender: self];
> }}
> ```

`prepareForSegue` method is as below:

> -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
>
> ```
>     CoViewController *destination =
>     [segue destinationViewController];
>
>
>     destination.name = _name;
>
>  };
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe when you change the `viewController` you do a `modalPresentation` instead of doing a `push`. So basically the slide doesn't work because it doesn't have a `navigationController` as `rootviewController` anymore.

Please show what are you doing there when you change the view.

Comment: Can't we allocate the navigationController as rootviewController in the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    
    if(tableView == self.tableView1)
    {
    
 
    
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"changeVC"
                              sender: self];
    }

Comment: try `[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller_initiated_from_stroryboard animated:NO];`

Comment: Or try modifying the segue to make PUSH instead of MODAL.

Comment: after using PUSH, it slides up but when sliding back to original position the following error occurs---->'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController qwerty:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: I'm using this class----> https://github.com/meiwin/MWFSlideNavigationViewController

Comment: it seems that you call a method that doesn't exists in the class `ViewController`

Comment: I saw how it works , now if the view slides the problem is solved , you must check your own methods and see what happens there.

Comment: I have checked evrything...This is only happening when I change instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier in the AppDelegate from myViewController to Navigation Controller in order to use PUSH.

Comment: it would've been much easier if I could've seen your project, I'm sure you are doing something wrong there, I don't think you need to instantiate the navigationcontroller as long as your viewcontroller is embeded inside it .

Comment: I modified with HomeVC as you said and the problem is that `MWFSlideNavigationViewController`that you use is nil

Comment: Can you please elaborate? how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Leave the project with `homeVC` and instead of presenting the `ViewController` you just make an `IBAction` on the `UIButton` **Button** that calls `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` so you present the view modally again.

Comment: I really appreciate your time & effort Sorin! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad that i could help Alik!

Comment: hey Sorin! I'm having an issue with the same class. Since it requires to initWithRootViewController the VC where sliding takes place. Now whenever the app enters background and then becomes active, it starts with the initWithRootViewController VC, instead of the VC where the user last was. Can you please suggest how to fix this?

Comment: You need to be a little more specifif, I need to see the code, first you can check the methods of the app delegate and see if anything goes on there, when the app is going to background.

Comment: Missed this line in applicationWillResignActive. It was causing the problem  [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];  Thanks ;)